# Can I print an online image to frame it for personal use?

Tags: copyright, licensing

I found some beautiful hi-res images online and want to print them just to frame and hang in my home.

The images came from personal websites of photographers or news sites like AP.

Is this legal?

Comment: Have you considered asking the photographer if they already have a print for sale?

Comment: It makes no mention on the site of prints for sale.

Comment: Then I would contact the photographer and ask.

Comment: Typically, yes, this falls into fair use territory. Though note that what is truly fair use vs. not is typically handled on a case-by-case, judge-by-judge basis. Would anyone sue you for printing a photo and hanging it on your wall? Likely, no.

Comment: Would you have any source for this?
What if I printed it and gave it as a gift to someone?

Comment: Google 'copyright and fair use' to find all sorts of information on the topic. Remember copyright law isn't black and white. It's entirely gray.

Comment: If you care enough to come here and ask then you probably shouldn't do it for psychological reasons.

Comment: What country are you living?

Comment: Most countries do not have a fair use clause. If it didnt have a license then no you can not print it without permission. No you wont get caught.

Comment: I don't think it is ilegal ever if you give the credit at the author and don't sell the printed image. But you should contact the artist and ask him or her before.

Comment: @Aradnix its a contract violation. Like all copyright issues.

Comment: @joojaa what about the copyleft and Creative Commons?

Comment: @Aradnix same thing just permissive license

Comment: @Aradnix Attribution does NOT have anything to do with copyright law. You do not get a pass by citing the source. Copyright remains despite permissions, credits, attributions, licensing, etc. Consult with an informed Intellectual Property reference in your jurisdiction. Make informed decisions.

Comment: @Stan I didn't mean that, but it's good to have clarity in the concepts, even if it's practically five years later.

Answer (score 1):

While it's highly unlikely you'd face a lawsuit over one print, it technically wouldn't fall under 'fair use' standards, from what I see.  A photographer or their employer inherently owns copyright on the image.

According to [U.S. copyright law](http://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-fairuse.html), "There may be situations in which the reproduction of a photograph may be a “fair use” under the copyright law. Information about fair use may be found at: www.copyright.gov/fls/fl102.html."  That page states "One of the rights accorded to the owner of copyright is the right to reproduce or to authorize others to reproduce the work in copies or phonorecords."

Comment: The last sentence essentially defines copyright. Fair use is an EXCEPTION to that broad definition.

Comment: True.  In that sentence, I was simply illustrating that U.S. copyright law does clearly define a photographers' right to reproduction.  There's no grey area as far as that goes.  'Fair use' is a grey area, I know.  That's why I included that first quote, referencing the fair use information url.  Trying to keep the answer directly about the question 'is it legal?'

Comment: Even when your answer is right, the OP didn't state he is living in the United States.